# What's a POSIX function for creating a temporary directory securely?

Tags: security, unix, directory, posix, mkdir

For the task of creating a temporary directory in `/tmp`,
how would one choose between `mkdtemp`, `mkstemp`, etc., for portable code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I presume you need to create a temporary directory inside a directory where other users may have write permission.

As an administrator, you should set things up so that each user has its own `TMPDIR` (e.g. with [pam-tmpdir](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libpam-tmpdir) — or even better with [per-process namespaces](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=217), but that takes more setup). As an application writer, however, you can't assume this, so you need to cope with a world-writable `/tmp`.

The right function here is [`mkdtemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html), since [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) can only create regular files. `mkdtemp` was only introduced in POSIX.1 2008, so in principle it might not be available on all POSIX platforms yet. However, it has been available on major platforms for a long time:

- on OpenBSD since [2.2](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkdtemp&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD+2.2) (1997)
- on FreeBSD since [2.2.7](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkdtemp&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+2.2.7-RELEASE) (1998)
- on NetBSD since [1.4](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkdtemp&sektion=3&manpath=NetBSD+1.4) (1998)
- on [OSX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mkdtemp.3.html) since… 10.0?
- on Linux (with Glibc) since Glibc 2.2 (1999)
- in dietlibc since at least 2001
- in uClibc since its beginning, I think
- in [MINIX 3](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/html3/mkdtemp.html)
- on Solaris only since [Solaris 10](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2243/6n4i0997q/index.html)

So in practice, you can safely go with `mkdtemp`. If you need a fallback, include the OpenBSD implementation in your source.