# Is there an equivalent of O_TMPFILE for directories?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Ideally, I want to have a directory that is not visible in the filesystem and that will be automatically removed when it's last open file descriptor is closed. It's contents would only be accessible through `openat()`, `fstatat()`, etc.

For regular files, this behaviour is achieved by giving the `O_TMPFILE` flag to `open()`. However, `mkdir()` doesnt have a flags parameter.

Assuming I have the latest linux kernel available, is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a POSIX function for creating a temporary directory securely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573920/whats-a-posix-function-for-creating-a-temporary-directory-securely)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all. This question is about Linux and asking for a directory-based variant of a Linux-specific feature; the pseudo-duplicate is about standards-conforming ways to make temp dirs.

Comment: Paul: Not really...`mkdtemp()` is what I use right now, but it's visible to other users and processes and still has to be removed manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, and don't expect it to be possible. Unlike files, which can have zero or more pathnames (due to hard links and unlinked files), directories have exactly one pathname, and it would probably break some valid application usage if the OS did not meet this expectation.

Comment: Notice that the assumption “directories have exactly one pathname” is not universally true and relying on it is dangerous. Some systems support hardlinks on directories. Other systems (like Linux) allow you to mount the same file system twice on two different paths, giving you two symlink-free paths to the same directory.

Comment: You can have a directory that has exactly one parent, and yet is unreachable from others using the FS. To do this, open an fd to a directory and `chroot` elsewhere. You can operate on it via `openat` and friends. Re breakage: this case did expose a bug in glibc https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1533836